# How to delete the parent of an anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an requirement of deleting the parent element of an anchor tag. I am adding div and anchor inside it dynamically. below is my code, Please help me out

```
  $("<div>"+offer+"<a href='javascript:deleteOrder(this.parent)'>X</a></div>").appendTo($('#resultTable #resultRow td')[selectedOrder-1]);


function deleteOrder(obj)
        {
            $(obj).parent().remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would change how you implement this:

```
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "#").addClass("offer");
$("<div>").text(offer).append(a).appendTo("#resultTable");
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.offer").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

You're using jQuery but you're inlining your Javascript. This is very "un-jQuery", which instead encourages [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). I've used [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to handle binding that event handler to dynamically created elements. This is (imho) a far cleaner solution.

Also, you can create markup the way you are but it can be problematic. For example, what if `offer` includes a `<`? Or something else that needs to be escaped? It's better to use functions suited to the job that take of all escaping for you (as I've done). Also, certainly in jQuery 1.4+ and possibly earlier, `$("<a>")` is *much* faster than full markup as the above uses `document.createElement()` rather than `innerHTML`, which can be really slow on some browsers.

From [jQuery 1.4 Released – Full Release Notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14):

> ```
> jQuery(“<div>”) jQuery(“<div/>”) and jQuery(“<div></div>”)
> ```
>
> All three now use the same code path
>   (using `document.createElement`),
>   improving performance for
>   `jQuery("<div></div>")`. Note that if
>   you specify attributes, we use the
>   browser’s native parsing (using
>   innerHTML).

Lastly, you can pass a selector to `appendTo()`. No need to pass it a jQuery object.